# unfortunately app has stopped bug in brain game app

Tags: java, android, xml, debugging, android-studio

hello community I'm hamza and I'm new to android development I followed too many tutorials and the best one is Mr rob percival one in UDEMY , and I'm creating now simple brain game app which calculate how many operation you can solve in a minute and after finishing coding the app won't even lunch it stacks at the message unfortunately app has stopped , thank you for helping me debugging the code because I don't want to look at no one's code thanks you very much I appreciate

JAVA MAIN CODE :

```
package com.example.hfpro.braintrainer;

import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    // Layouts Pointers
    final TextView counter = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.counter) ;
    final TextView operation = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.operation) ;
    final TextView button1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.choice1) ;
    final TextView button2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.choice2) ;
    final TextView button3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.choice3) ;
    final TextView button4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.choice4) ;
    final TextView total = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.total) ;
    final TextView result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result) ;
    final Button start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start) ;



    int counterNumber ;
    int correctResult ;
    int score = 0 ;
    int levels = 1 ;
    Random random = new Random() ;

    public void operation(View view)
    {
        String temp = String.valueOf(score)+" / " + String.valueOf(levels) ;
        total.setText(temp);
        int num1 = Math.abs(random.nextInt()%50) ;
        int num2 = Math.abs(random.nextInt()%50) ;
        correctResult = num1 + num2 ;
        temp = String.valueOf(num1) + " + " +String.valueOf(num2) + "  = ? " ;
        operation.setText(temp);
        // set the correct result in a result suggetoin
        int correctResultPosition = Math.abs(random.nextInt()%4) ;
        switch (correctResultPosition)
        {
            case 0 :
                button1.setText(String.valueOf(correctResult));
                break;
            case 1 :
                button2.setText(String.valueOf(correctResult));
                break;
            case 2 :
                button3.setText(String.valueOf(correctResult));
                break;
            case 3 :
                button4.setText(String.valueOf(correctResult));
                break;
            default:
        }
    }

    public void start(final View view)
    {
        // quetions() ;
        counter.setText("60");
        start.animate().alpha(0).setDuration(500) ;
        // timer
        final Handler handler = new Handler() ;
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                counterNumber = Integer.valueOf((String)counter.getText()) ;
                counterNumber -- ;
                if(counterNumber == 0 )
                {
                    //timeFinished
                    String res =   "Time is up your score is :"+ String.valueOf(score) + " :::";
                    result.setText(res);

                }
                counter.setText(String.valueOf(counterNumber));

                handler.postDelayed(this , 1000) ;
            }
        } ;
        handler.post(runnable) ;

    }


    public void checkResult(View view)
    {
        switch (view.getId())
        {
            case R.id.choice1 :
                if(correctResult == Integer.valueOf((String)button1.getText()))
                    {
                        score++ ;
                        String str = String.valueOf(score) + " / " + String.valueOf(levels) ;
                        total.setText(str);
                    }
                levels++ ;
                break;
            case R.id.choice2 :
                if(correctResult == Integer.valueOf((String)button2.getText()))
                {
                    score++ ;
                    String str = String.valueOf(score) + " / " + String.valueOf(levels) ;
                    total.setText(str);
                }
                levels++ ;
                break;
            case R.id.choice3 :
                if(correctResult == Integer.valueOf((String)button3.getText()))
                {
                    score++ ;
                    String str = String.valueOf(score) + " / " + String.valueOf(levels) ;
                    total.setText(str);
                }
                levels++ ;
                break;
            case R.id.choice4:
                if(correctResult == Integer.valueOf((String)button4.getText()))
                {
                    score++ ;
                    String str = String.valueOf(score) + " / " + String.valueOf(levels) ;
                    total.setText(str);
                }
                levels++ ;
                break;
            default:
        }
        this.operation(view);
    }




}
```

and this is the XML code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.hfpro.braintrainer.MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="@string/RES1"
            android:id="@+id/choice1"
            android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:background="#e1e2b7" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="@string/RES2"
            android:id="@+id/choice2"
            android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
            android:background="#6b4ec8" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="@string/RES3"
            android:id="@+id/choice3"
            android:layout_gravity="left|bottom"
            android:background="#65ba8c" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="@string/RES4"
            android:id="@+id/choice4"
            android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
            android:background="#dcb27e" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/start"
            android:id="@+id/start"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:onClick="start" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="43dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="@string/operation"
            android:id="@+id/operation"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
            android:onClick="operation" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="@string/result"
            android:id="@+id/counter"
            android:layout_gravity="left|top" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="@string/counter"
            android:id="@+id/total"
            android:layout_gravity="right|top" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="@string/result"
            android:id="@+id/result"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom" />

    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and I use string.xml and there he is :

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">BrainTrainer</string>
    <string name="RES1">RES1</string>
    <string name="RES2">RES2</string>
    <string name="RES3">RES3</string>
    <string name="RES4">RES4</string>
    <string name="operation">operation</string>
    <string name="counter">60</string>
    <string name="level">0/1</string>
    <string name="start">Start</string>
    <string name="result">result</string>



</resources>
```

Comment: Post your stack trace.  It will tell you where the problem is and what it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, still post your stack traces in the future.  But I can tell you your problem-  you can't put findViewById calls outside of a function like that.  YOu need to initialize those variables in onCreate and make them non-final.  Until the contentView is set by setContentView, there are no views to find so findViewById will return null.

Comment: thanks a lot it works very well now hope you having an awesome day :) peace .